# Symfony4 SQLite in memory for testing can't get it to work

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine, in-memory

I'm trying to use SQLite in memory db to run tests in Symfony 4, but I cant get it to work.
My config looks like this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
                url: ':memory:'
                memory: true
                #charset: utf8mb4
                #default_table_options:
                #    charset: utf8mb4
                #    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using? Is this your `config_test.yml` or `config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml`? How does your `phpunit.xml.dist` look?

Comment: @dbrumann I've tried `config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml` and `phpunit.xml.dist` but no success.

Answer (score 2):

[EDITED on 2019-01-27]

In my case,
config/packages/test/doctrine.yaml :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:  pdo_sqlite
        memory:  true
        charset: UTF8
```

But, for the fonctionnal testing, you need to create dB ( db in memory= not created and not persisted !)

Exemple :

```
<?php
 // tests/Repository/MyRepositoryTest.php
 namespace App\Tests\Controller;

 use App\Repository\MyController;
 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

 class MyRepositoryTest extend WebTestCase {

     public function testSearch()
     {
         $container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
         $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine')->getManager();

         // Runs the schema update tool using our entity metadata
         $metadatas = $entityManager->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();
         $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($entityManager);
         $schemaTool->updateSchema($metadatas);

         // @TODO : now you can test !
     }
 }
```

Comment: how does your config file looks like? Because I create and populate db before tests.

Comment: I've seen Adam Wathan in his TDD Laravel course uses sqlite in memory for functional tests. 

Basically I dont care about data in between tests. I prefer empty data, and controlling it trough my tests.